# how to remove Divider line from split view application in ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hi friend i want hide divider line in split view .divider line means when application is run landscape mode the 2 view is show one left side and another right side so between this two view divider is show i want to hide this divider 
i try this code in appdelegate class but this is not working proper

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    UIView *coverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(320, 44, 1, 704)];
    [coverView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1x704.png"]]];

    [splitViewController.view addSubview:coverView];  
    [window addSubview:splitViewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible with UISplitViewController. But if you are feeling adventurous, you can try [MGSplitViewController](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController) by Matt Gemmell. You can customize that divider until your heart is content.

Comment: I have been down voted. Somebody knows a better answer but is keeping it a secret?